# laravel nested relationships pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

this is my database tables that each product can have multiple attributes and each attribute has multiple values that can be selected in the Select Box on the product edit page.

**attribute table:**

```
+-----------------------+
|       attributes      |
+====+======+===========+
| id | name | type      |
+----+------+-----------+
| 1  | size | selectbox |
+----+------+-----------+
| 2  | ...  | ....      |
+----+------+-----------+
```

**attribute_values table:**

```
+-----------------------------+
|       attribute_values      |
+====+==============+=========+
| id | attribute_id | value   |
+----+--------------+---------+
| 1  | 1            | sample1 |
+----+--------------+---------+
| 2  | 1            | sample2 |
+----+--------------+---------+
| 3  | 1            | sample3 |
+----+--------------+---------+
```

**products table:**

```
+----------------+
|    products    |
+====+===========+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | product 1 |
+----+-----------+
| 2  | product 2 |
+----+-----------+
```

**attribute_product table:**

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|             attribute_product             |
+====+============+==============+==========+
| id | product_id | attribute_id | value_id |
+----+------------+--------------+----------+
| 1  | 1          | 1            | 1        |
+----+------------+--------------+----------+
| 2  | 1          | 1            | 2        |
+----+------------+--------------+----------+
```

**relationships**

```
class Attribute extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
}



class AttributeValue extends Model
{

}


class Product extends Model
{
    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class, 'attribute_product')
            ->withPivot('value_id');
    }
}
```

**blade:**

```
@foreach($product->attributes as $attribute)
    Attribute Name: {{ $attribute->name }}
    <select>
        @foreach($attribute->values as $value)
            <option id="{{ $value->id }}">{{ $value->id }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
@endforeach
```

**how to add 'selected' to select box selected options (value_id in attribute_product)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do

```
@foreach($product->attributes as $attribute)
    Attribute Name: {{ $attribute->name }}
    <select>
        @foreach($attribute->values as $value)
            <option id="{{ $value->id }}" {{ $attribute->pivot->value_id == $value->id ? 'selected' :  '' }} >{{ $value->id }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
@endforeach
```

Comment: The solution for select multi selection was a little different, but your solution helped me to some extent.